# ReactJs - How to convert a current date to ISO 8601 format?

Tags: jquery, json, reactjs, date, iso8601

In reactjs application, I am getting a date in `2020-04-03T09:22:20.45-04:00` format. It is in `ISO 8601` date format

Also I need to convert current date and time to `ISO 8601` format, how can I do this?

Comment: You can use https://momentjs.com/ for date format as per your needs.

Comment: To convert I should know which is this format right? In `momentjs` I didn't get this format.

Answer (score 1):

Current Date format in ISOString using momentjs.

```
moment().toISOString(new Date());
```

Also you can format your dates in any format you want using momentjs:

```
moment().format();
```

You should check the docs of momentjs.

Answer (score 0):

`moment().toISOString(); // or format() - see below`

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/